# Error: Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection

Tags: r

I am trying to run dssp function using bio3d package in R. But I am getting error.

```
library("bio3d")
pdb <- read.pdb("1CRN")
x <- dssp(pdb, exepath="C:/dssp/dssp.exe")

Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection
```

Any suggestions please.

Comment: Do examples in `dssp` work for you? Try including exepath in the example. If not, you could always include path to dssp.exe into your PATH and avoid typing exepath all togehter.

Comment: I've answered your question where you asked it originally: http://biostar.stackexchange.com/questions/19053/secondary-structure-analysis-with-dssp-in-r/19118#19118

Comment: @neilfws That link is broken for me, any chance you could duplicate the answer here as well?

Comment: @ThomasH - here is the working link: http://www.biostars.org/p/19002/

Answer (score 0):

To solve it you need to fix the dssp function paramenters:

fix(dssp)

rewrite the following line:

system(paste(exepath, "dssp **-c** ", infile, **" "**, outfile, sep = ""), ignore.stderr = TRUE)

"-i" istead of **"-c"** and "-o" intead of **" "**

chears